# The difference between hedging and replicationg methods of deriving option prices

Tags: option-pricing, hedging, replication

For deriving, say European, option prices, is there a difference between the replication approach and the hedging approach? More specifically, is there a situation where the hedging approach will not give the pricing while the replicating approach will? Perhaps caused by some restriction on funding methods?

Comment: If you are hedging an option and you look in a mirror you see a person replicating the option. (In other words it is only a difference in point of view).

Comment: @AlexC: I agree with you for the cases where the borrowing and lending rates are both the same and without restrictions. What about when funding methods are restricted, such as either when borrowing rate and lending rate are different, or say short is prohibited?